# Generalization of Triangulations in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

There are some results on planar triangulations I was trying to generalize to a larger class of graphs.

So, what I am looking for is, a set of graphs such that the intersection of this set and the set of planar graphs is the set of planar triangulations.

Is there a ``sensible'' such set? Or any such set that is already well-known? I am somewhat new to this area of mathematics so there could be something common I am missing.

One potential set of graphs I was thinking of (let's call them `nice'), for example, is the set of graphs ``generated'' by the following:

- take a nice graph of order $n$, along with some `designated' set of triangles
- add a vertex $x$, adjacent to the vertices of exactly one designated triangle $abc$, and replace $abc$ in the set of designated triangles with $abx$, $bcx$, $cax$

with this being applied recursively, the only nice graph of order 3 being the triangle, and itself being a designated triangle

This, I believe, retains the nice property of the number of edges always being $3n-6$ when $n$ is the number of vertices, so seems a nice generalization to me. I believe it generates all the planar triangulations and no other planar graphs (please correct me if I am wrong). However, the definition is somewhat convoluted.

Another possibility I thought about is to look at graphs such that, for every cycle, for every edge in this cycle, there is a triangle containing this edge. Is this in fact equivalent? Not sure.

This is quite an open-ended question. I did look around but I didn't find any sensible class of graphs which matches my description.

Comment: Starting with a single triangle, the set of graphs generated this way is the set of [Apollonian networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_network), which does not include all planar triangulations.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Could you show me an example of a planar triangulation that is not an Apollonian network? Thank you!

Comment: [This graph](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/19170) should work. (It's two pentagonal pyramids glued along their pentagonal faces; it's not drawn in a planar fashion but it is possible to do that.) In an Apollonian network, the most recently added vertex always has degree $3$; in this graph, the minimum degree is $4$. (So I guess it now occurs to me that the [octahedral graph](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/226) is another, smaller example.)

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I said doesn't work then. I just realised I could literally restrict to graphs with 3n-6 edges, but that doesn't really give me any ``triangulation''-y properties :(